# What does Visual Studio have to do with HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography?

Tags: visual-studio, registry

VS 2010 becomes unresponsive randomly. A look into process monitor shows it waits in a loop on RegQueryValue operation on HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider Types\Type 001\Name key. Why does Visual Studio need to do this? Is there a way to get around this?
Have tried resetting devenv and stopping Windows Cryptography Services.

Comment: I wish someone would respond to this.  I've had this issue with both VS2012 and VS2013.  It absolutely hammers these keys (per process monitor).